# static settings in flask.

Tags: css, flask

I set static_folder and static_url_path below:

hello.py

```
app = Flask(__name__,  static_folder='static', static_url_path='')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/schedule/<user>')
def schedule(user):
    return render_template("schedule.html", user=user)
```

and project directory setting below:

project
-hello.py
- templates
  - home.html
  - schedule.html  
- static
  - bootstrap

and I set CSS in html files;

```
<!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

localhost:8000/home is fine.

but  localhost:8000/schedule/test, web page is broken css.

how to change static folder or url path?

Comment: `localhost:8000/schedule/test` return `schedule.html` for me. Better use `url_for('static', path='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')` and use url prefix for static, because it can have conflicts when one url satisfy two endpoints (in this case resolving priority by url length and arguments). However with prefix and `url_for` you can easy setup nginx rules for fast static responces or put static to external servers like CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Does your css files in the static directory? If it is,according to your code and project structure when you try to load Flat UI it cannot find flat-ui.css. You need point to relative path of the css file.

```
<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="./static/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="static/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```